# I want to get numeric data from string. How to do that in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I want to get numeric data from string. How to do that in python???

For e.g. From string "data23/45 data"
extract 23 and 45

Comment: What might you have attempted before asking us for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are hundreds of ways, but one way is to use a regular expression to split the string into digit groups, and a list comprehension to convert the values to integers;

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "data23/45 data"
>>> [int(x) for x in re.split('[^\d]+', a) if x]
[23, 45]
```

`re.split('[^\d]+', a)` will split on non digits, which leaves only the digit groups in the result. The outer list comprehension will convert all non empty values in the result to integers.

Of course, if you want the digit groups still as strings, you can use the simpler;

```
>>> [x for x in re.split('[^\d]+', a) if x]
['23', '45']
```